# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied?

Tags: asp.net

In my web application i am using video conversion, i am getting error like

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied

video conversion is working fine in localserver. when i upload in online it is giving error like this can u help me.

error like..

Access is denied
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied

Source Error:

```
Line 76:               ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = " -i \"" + video + "\"    -vframes 1 -ss 00:00:10 -s 150x150 -f image2 -vcodec mjpeg \"" + thumb + "\""; // arguments !
Line 77:               ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = Page.MapPath("FFMPEG\\ffmpeg.exe"); //Page.MapPath("\\User\\Trailorvideos\\ffmpeg.exe");  //Page.MapPath(".") + "/ffmpeg.exe";
Line 78:               ffmpeg.Start(); // start !
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using shared hosting? Probably your code is running at a lower trust level on your hosting provider that it is on your local server and you have no acces to COM.

You can read about trust levels [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyts434y.aspx) many shared hosting providors set the trust level to medium.

Comment: Ya it is shared hosting @Ben Robinson

Comment: Is there any space problem in domain, it is my doubt only

Comment: Or is there any folder permission required

Comment: The link works fine here it is again http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyts434y.aspx

Comment: It is probably not a space or folder permision problem, you are probably simply not allowed to call COM on the shared hosting, you could easily crash the whole server if you did something wrong so shared hosting providers limit the scope of what you can do. I doubt you would ever get something that is as CPU instensive as transcoding video to work on shared hosting.